# Do I need to ask for Personnal Information when using Paypal?

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I'm writing a basic ecommerce website and the only payment mean is Paypal.

Users don't have to register however, they will be mailed their product.

As far as I know you to be registered to use Paypal, and therefore Paypal stores your personnal informations (Address, names, etc..)

So my question is do I need to ask to users to enter their personnal informations while it is available on Paypal, and I guess, hope, there is an API to retrieve them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask for their e-mail addresses where they want the product delivered, as it do not neccesarily matches the one they used on PayPal. You will get an invoice in e-mail form PayPal for accounting purposes that sould do.

If you need customer details, you should look into the [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) feature of PayPal, you basically give a URL on your site, then PayPal POST-s all the details to that script. This way you can be sure that the customer actually payed for the services.

There is an extra setep involved, to verify the details you got in your IPN script as anyone who knows its URL can post anything to your script. Also a good idea to put your it into a random directory like `dsf6dfsjj345432f8dsfj5j243826d` and publish no liks to it, to minimze the possibility of someone trying to play around with your script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not need to store a client's details on your end. Paypal just requires pricing, product and an invoice reference. They manage storing and securing customer CC details (for example). You might consider storing *some* client details (such as email, name, address and so on.... but not CC details).

Paypal will often post back order details, which do include client details (i.e. email, contact, shipping details and so on). I, however, am not entirely sure that they supply an API where this information can queried retrospectively.... maybe someone else can help on this on.

HTH and good luck

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I only need an email for further contacts if needed, but if Paypal returns back shipping address and name it's enough, I'll be able to store my order with the customer information in my own database

Answer (score 0):

Look into their Express Checkout approach. That is designed for "preparing" a transaction which you later on finalize from your end, after you have received the customers shipping address. What you decide to do with that is up to you.